# VBA Format Non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to format non-contiguous columns.  My columns are defined using END(xl.Down). I am using the following after defining the range.

```
For Each rCell In MyRange         
    rCell.NumberFormat = "0.00"     
Next rCell
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, providing `rCell` and `MyRange` are correctly declared and `MyRange` is correctly set.  It would probably be best if you include in the question the code that you are using to set `MyRange`, and also say what is not working at the moment.

Comment: This is not a question, please post an error or behavior that is failing.

Comment: `MyRange.NumberFormat = "0.00" `

Answer (score 0):

Use end(xlup) instead of xldown to find the bottom cell
(Assuming you're finding the max row of column A in preparation for setting a range based on it)

```
rMax = Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row
```